# On press enter key in textarea prevent line break and remove the text in the textarea

Tags: javascript, newline

I create a textarea and javascript code that removes the text in the textarea on press enter
my problem is that when press enter it break a line, but I want to prevent the line break.
this is my code for removing text from textarea on press enter:

```
if(e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey){
function clear() {
$("#mytxt :input").each(  function() {
    $(this) .val('');
    });
}
}
<textarea id="mytxt"></textarea>
```

so how can I prevent the line break while using my function?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `e.preventDefault();` to the end of your function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey)
 {
   //write your code here

   return false;
 }
  <textarea id="mytxt"></textarea>
```