# Any way to preform keyboard inputs on HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, html

I know how to preform clicks on html objects using .click(). But if I wanted to type the letter a or do something similar, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Do you mean you want to press a and it will do something?

Comment: onClick(()=>{document.getElementById('yourelementid').innerHTML += 'A';})

Comment: If you would move event function to separate function, then you can execute it without even triggering keyup event!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [On press enter key in textarea prevent line break and remove the text in the textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17634977/on-press-enter-key-in-textarea-prevent-line-break-and-remove-the-text-in-the-tex)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!, Unfortunately, This question is a little bit too vague, it asks very generally for what would constitute a tutorial instead of asking a specific question. Therefore it is not suitable for stackoverflow as Stackoverflow is not a tutorial provider. Askers are expected to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and show us the problems they are facing. Please review the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section for tips on asking questions that are well-suited for the site. Goodluck

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

to perform click any input use:

```js
document.getElementById('elementID').click();
```

to add letter to input text use:

```js
document.getElementById('yourelementid').innerHTML += 'A';
```

for better answer, please explain your question more.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to extract input text from an element and then trying to populate to a label or html field.
You need to register an event listener in your js snippet so that it will listen to changes to that input field. This may not be efficient but you can do as follows :

```
<html>
   <body>
      <p id='p1'>Test Default Text</p>
      <input id='i1' type="text" onkeyPress="myFunction()">
      <script>
         function myFunction() {
         var inputelem = document.getElementById("i1");
         document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = inputelem.value;
         
         }
         
         var inputelem = document.getElementById("p1");
         inputelem.addEventListener('keypress', myFunction);
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```